# IPython.display.Audio cannot correctly handle `.ogg` file type?

Tags: python, ipython, mime, jupyter, ogg

I was doing some audio analysis stuff with Jupyter and tried to play `.ogg` files with `IPython.display.Audio`. Since PyCharm often failed to open big `.ipynb` files, I mostly used web browser to view my Notebook files at `localhost:8888`.

[image]

This picture is what I get with Chrome. As you can see, **FailToDisplay.ogg** is taken from my work, the audio play bar is not activated. **File-ACDC_-_Back_In_Black-sample.ogg** and **song sample.mp3** are all downloaded from Internet. The integrity of 3 files are all validated, i.e., they can all be played correctly with audio players.

I also tested it with Microsoft Edge and Firefox, and the results are mostly the same. 2 `.ogg` playbars are all inactive while `.mp3` playbar is active and works perfectly. So I guess the problem is not web browser dependent.

I checked the html source code of these 3 audio playbars with Chrome Developer Tool, they are all like:

```
<audio controls="controls">
                    <source src="data:None;base64,VERYLONGTEXT" type="None">
                    Your browser does not support the audio element.
                </audio>
```

The `type` for mp3 is `audio/mpeg` and `type` for ogg is `None`. After some google search, I guess this has something to do with **MIME** type. So I inspected 3 audio files with command `mimetype`:

```
$ mimetype ./*
./AudioDisplayErrorTest.ipynb:          text/plain
./FailToDisplay.ogg:                    audio/x-vorbis+ogg
./File-ACDC_-_Back_In_Black-sample.ogg: video/x-theora+ogg
./song sample.mp3:                      audio/mpeg
```

Not very strange. Then I find this blog post [How to set MIMETYPES on server : Forums : PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/333/) and tested my python MIME type settings:

```
>>> import mimetypes
>>> mimetypes.guess_type("foo.ogg")
(None, None)
```

Now I don't know what to do next with this kind of situation. Is this just a bug of Jupyter or IPython or system-wide? Where can I change this behavior?

My Python environment settings are

```
audioread==2.1.4
ipykernel==4.4.1
ipython==5.1.0
ipython-genutils==0.1.0
ipywidgets==4.1.1
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==4.3.0
jupyter-console==5.0.0
jupyter-core==4.1.1
librosa==0.4.3
nbconvert==4.2.0
nbformat==4.0.1
notebook==4.2.2
numpy==1.11.1
openpyxl==2.3.2
pydub==0.16.5
```

Comment: OK, I figured it out by myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since no one gives a hint, I guess I'll have to work alone...

First look into the source code of `IPython.display.audio`: [ipython/display.py at 48b01aadcbb6a53d2c77fa250c8a4344931c357c · ipython/ipython](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/48b01aadcbb6a53d2c77fa250c8a4344931c357c/IPython/lib/display.py)

```
def _repr_html_(self):
    src = """
            <audio controls="controls" {autoplay}>
                <source src="{src}" type="{type}" />
                Your browser does not support the audio element.
            </audio>
          """
    return src.format(src=self.src_attr(),type=self.mimetype, autoplay=self.autoplay_attr())
```

This is the code that generates html source code of audio control block, `type` is assigned from `self.mimetype`. And `self.mimetype` is derived from `reload()`:

```
    if self.filename is not None:
        self.mimetype = mimetypes.guess_type(self.filename)[0]
    elif self.url is not None:
        self.mimetype = mimetypes.guess_type(self.url)[0]
    else:
        self.mimetype = "audio/wav"
```

It's obvious if `mimetypes.guess_type("filename.ogg")[0]` gets `None`, then we have `type == None`, which results an inactive audio control block.

From [18.7. mimetypes — Map filenames to MIME types — Python 2.7.12 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mimetypes.html) I learned that MIME types can be loaded from file or dynamically added with `mimetypes.add_type()`. It also said by default `mimetypes` will load from Windows registry. I tried to modify system-wide MIME type settings of `.ogg` with one small utility [FileTypesMan - Alternative to 'File Types' manager of Windows](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) but it did not reflect on `mimetypes`, so I guess I'll have to let it go.

At last I realized that a monkey patch before `IPython.display.Audio` was used will possibly work and it really does:

[image]

It may not be perfect to solve the problem, but at least it works. So be it for now.